# Efficient way of upserting dependent tables in SQLAlchemy and/or PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy has a [`merge`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html?highlight=merge#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge) function, which inserts or updates, but it only works on the primary key conflict, not on an arbitrary specified constraint key.

Hence, I tried using PostgreSQL's dialect, which provides function [`on_conflict_do_update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=on_conflict_do_update#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Insert.on_conflict_do_update). This works OK, but if you have a related parent-child joined table relationship, where ***child table's primary key is also a foreign key to the parent table's primary key***, the things start to get complicated, and I couldn't find an effective way to do the upsert (without the foreign key constraint, you can get away with [`cte`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.cte), though).

Preferably, I would like to do this in a single execution statement, since otherwise I can just filter out the rows which exist, run the update on each of them separately, and run [`add_all`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.add_all) on the set of the remaining rows which don't exist yet.

I couldn't even find an efficient way of doing this in pure PostgreSQL, so solution in pure PostgreSQL is appreciated as well.